# Acesso a localização no windows 10 (aplicativo universal)

Tags: c#, windows

Eu estava tentando converter um antigo projeto meu feito pra Windows phone 8.1 para um aplicativo universal para Windows 10, quando me deparei com esse erro abaixo.

A pergunta é, como faço para corrigi-lo?, como faço para pedir acesso a localização de um computador mesmo? , tipo sei la ... usando alocaliz~çao via ip na falta de um gps

> An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> WinRT information: Seu Aplicativo não tem permissão para acessar dados de localização. Verifique se ID_CAP_LOCATION está definido no manifesto do aplicativo em seu telefone, se você ativou a localização selecionando Configurações > Localização.
>
> Additional information: Acesso negado.
>
> Seu Aplicativo não tem permissão para acessar dados de localização. Verifique se ID_CAP_LOCATION está definido no manifesto do aplicativo em seu telefone, se você ativou a localização selecionando Configurações > Localização.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

`

Comment: Qual a versão do Windows e do Visual Studio?

Comment: visual studio 2015 e Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fornecer acesso à localização no Windows 10 é necessário adicionar  *DeviceCapability **location*** no *Package.appxmanifest*

```
 <Capabilities>
   <Capability Name="internetClient" />
   <DeviceCapability Name="location" />
 </Capabilities>
```

*Obs.*: Existe um script que pode ajudar a migrar apps 8.1 para Universal Windows Platform.
Ele está disponível em https://github.com/Win10DevGuideMVA/ProjectUpgradeUtility